# Erlang: "prepending" an element to a tuple

Tags: erlang

Is it possible to write a faster equivalent to this function?

```
prepend(X, Tuple) ->
  list_to_tuple([X | tuple_to_list(Tuple)]).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As prepending an element is the same as inserting it at position 1, you can use the built-in function [`erlang:insert_element/3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#insert_element-3):

```
> erlang:insert_element(1, {a, b}, z).
{z,a,b}
```

This function was added in Erlang/OTP R16A.

Answer (score 9):

It looks to me like that sort of thing is discouraged. If you want a list, use one.

[Getting Started with Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/seq_prog.html#id59176):

> Tuples have a fixed number of things in them.

Comment: Definitely, if you want a dynamic structure use lists instead.

Comment: My actual use case is that I have several functions which return "raw" tuples (e.g. `{Name, Age}`) and would prefer to turn them into tagged tuples (`{person, Name, Age}`). I don't want a dynamic structure at all.

Comment: is deeper structure ok for you? like {person, {Name, Age}}? So you could call function with this tag: {person, who(Args)}..

Answer (score 6):

If you have a finite number of possible tuple lengths, you could do this:

```
prepend(X, {}) -> {X};
prepend(X, {A}) -> {X, A};
prepend(X, {A, B}) -> {X, A, B};
prepend(X, {A, B, C}) -> {X, A, B, C}.
```

You can continue this pattern for as long as you need.