# Multiple (tuple-based) generators in list comprehension in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I am trying to filter a list of tuples based on whether the first element of the tuples matches the elements in another list.

For instance, the original list is

```
163>Shoppinglist.
[{oranges,2},{milk,1},{apples,2}]
```

If I try to use multiple generators with the `<-` notation, it loops and results in elements repeated more than once like this:

```
164> [(Item)||{Item,Unit}<-Shoppinglist, Item<-[apples,milk]].
[apples,milk,apples,milk,apples,milk]
```

This is explained nicely in the answer by Alexey Romanov in this question: [Multiple filters in list comprehension in Erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321265/multiple-filters-in-list-comprehension-in-erlang#). Based on this answer, I can do the below and it works fine.

```
165>[{Item}||{Item,Unit}<-Shoppinglist,(Item==apples) or (Item==milk)].
[apples, milk]
```

But this doesn't really meet my need, since I would like the second list `Item<-[apples,milk]` to come in as an input, and because it may not always be practical to manually list out all the matches like `(Item==apples) or (Item==milk)` for a very long list.

So is there any way to actually use multiple lists as generators? Or a more clever way to solve my problem..I only started very recently with Erlang (with the Pragmatic Programming and the LYSE books) so I still know very little.

Comment: shortly after writing the question, it occurred to me that I could convert the second list to a list of tuples and use just a single generator: `[Item||{Item,_Unit}<-[{apples,0},{milk,0}]].`  That introduces new things I don't know yet and are further up the learning curve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214821/list-to-list-of-tuples-convertion and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936613/erlang-prepending-an-element-to-a-tuple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1> Shoppinglist = [{oranges,2},{milk,1},{apples,2}].
[{oranges,2},{milk,1},{apples,2}]
2> Filterlist = [apples,milk].
[apples,milk]
```

First methode, filter the list directly :in list comprehension, the filter may be any statement that return false or true. good for memory footprint, bad for excution time if the filter list is big.

```
3> [Item || {Item,_} <- Shoppinglist, lists:member(Item,Filterlist)].
[milk,apples]
```

Second method, generate the cross product and filter. The cross product looks like [{{oranges,2},apples},{{milk,1},apples},{{apples,2},apples},{{oranges,2},milk},{{milk,1},milk},{{apples,2},milk}], I don't think it is really built but it help to understand how the filter works. bad for memory footprint, question mark for performance.

```
4> [Item1 || {Item1,_} <- Shoppinglist, Item2 <- Filterlist, Item1 == Item2].   
[milk,apples]
```

If the lists may be big, I think that the first solution is better, and if the code is critical (big lists, many calls) then I suggest to create a map from the filter list and then use this map as filter:

```
5> [Item || {Item,_} <- Shoppinglist, maps:get(Item,lists:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> maps:put(X,true,Acc) end, #{},Filterlist),false)].
[milk,apples]
```

Answer (score 2):

For my opinion, list comprehension is not appropriate tool for this task. I would rather prefer to create sets and find intersection:

```
 SList = [{oranges,2},{milk,1},{apples,2}].
 IList = [apples, milk].
 ISet = sets:from_list(IList).
 SSet = sets:from_list([I|{I,_} <- SList]).
 6> sets:to_list(sets:intersection(ISet, SSet)).
 [apples,milk]
```

Comment: converting to sets and doing ordinary set intersection is a very interesting approach, i think it will also be useful for other problems...